# Bug in MySQL query due to comparisons during joins

Tags: mysql

MySQL Server version: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1 - (Debian)

I've got a MySQL issue that is almost a year old. Have tried a few freelancers and while we got close, it was never totally solved.

I need to find the most recent outbound shipment for every product we have. And in the same row of results, the specific lot (including lot number and expiration date) of the product that was involved in that inventory adjustment.

The most recent version of this query is almost working but it has one fatal flaw (at least one). If the product only ever had one outbound shipment, it won't show up in the results. I'm assuming that is because on line 30 where a comparison is done, which looks like this

```
AND liai0.LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID > liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID
```

I'm assuming it is because the one and only adjustment for a product couldn't be greater than itself, it fails to be considered by the where clause. I've tested this by adding a second, fake outbound shipment, for a missing product. The query then returns the missing product.

That isn't the only line with a comparison like that. Perhaps the same problem could happen if there was only ever one location for a given product (line 23) and perhaps if there was only ever one lot for a product (line 16).

Here is the latest version of the query:

```
SELECT
    p.`ProductID`,
    p.`ProductName`,
    lot.`ProductLotID`,
    lot.`ExpirationDate`,
    lot.`LotNumber`,
    lia.`LocationInventoryAdjustmentID`,
    lia.`Created`,
    liai.`count`
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN product_lots AS lot ON lot.ProductID = p.ProductID
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM product_lots AS lot0
        WHERE lot0.ProductID = lot.ProductID
            AND lot0.ProductLotID > lot.ProductLotID
    )
INNER JOIN product_locations AS pl ON pl.ProductLotID = lot.ProductLotID
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM product_locations AS pl0
        WHERE pl0.ProductLotID = pl.ProductLotID
            AND pl0.ProductLocationID > pl.ProductLocationID
    )
INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustment_items AS liai ON liai.ProductLocationID = pl.ProductLocationID
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM location_inventory_adjustment_items AS liai0
        WHERE liai0.ProductLocationID = liai.ProductLocationID
            AND liai0.LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID > liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID
    )
INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustments AS lia ON lia.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID = liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID
INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustment_reasons AS liar ON liar.ReasonID = lia.ReasonID
WHERE liar.`Name` LIKE '%Out-Bound%'
ORDER BY p.ProductID ASC, liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID
```

And now the tables

Table `products`

```
ProductID     ProductName
1             Banana
2             Apple
3             Orange
4             Shirt
```

Table `product_lots`

```
ProductLotID     ProductID     ExpirationDate     LotNumber
20                1             2022-01-01         Chikita22
21                3             2023-12-01         Florida-9
22                4             NULL               HANES-001
23                1             2024-01-01         Chikita24
```

Table `product_locations`

```
ProductLocationID     ProductLotID     LocationCode     LocationType
30                    20               A-01-01-01       1 
31                    21               A-02-01-01       1
32                    22               12-03-01-01      2
33                    23               A-01-01-01       1
```

Table `location_inventory_adjustment_items`

```
LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID     LocationInventoryAdjustmentID     ProductLocationID     Count
40                                    50                                30                    100
41                                    51                                31                    200
42                                    52                                32                    300
43                                    53                                33                    150
```

Table `location_inventory_adjustments`

```
LocationInventoryAdjustmentID     LocationTypeID     ReasonID     Created
50                                1                  4            2020-01-01
51                                1                  4            2020-05-01
52                                2                  4            2020-06-01
53                                1                  4            2020-07-07
```

Table `location_inventory_adjustment_reasons`

```
ReasonID     Name                            Description
1            Discarded Product               Trash           
2            In-Bound Shipment               Delivery
3            Out-Bound Shipment              Product was shipped out
4            Out-Bound Shipment - FBA US     Product was shipped out to an Amazon fulfillment center in the US
5            Out-Bound Shipment - FBA UK     Product was shipped out to an Amazon fulfillment center in the UK
```

Now that the table structure is added, only the product Banana would be returned by the query since it is the only product to be involved in more than one inventory adjustment (more than one outbound shipment).

What can I do to fix this bug (in my query, obviously not a bug in MySQL)

Comment: What version of MySQL? With MySQL 8.0, you get window functions, which can make this kind of query a lot cleaner.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including the table structure you have. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: @BillKarwin Server version: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1 - (Debian)

Comment: @Progman Table structure added, and description updated too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ican't really explain it it must be one or other restricted wording.

But try, at least mysql 8 workbench doesn't mind

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products
>     (`ProductID` int, `ProductName` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO products
>     (`ProductID`, `ProductName`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Banana'),
>     (2, 'Apple'),
>     (3, 'Orange'),
>     (4, 'Shirt')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE product_lots
>     (`ProductLotID` int, `ProductID` int, `ExpirationDate` varchar(10), `LotNumber` varchar(9))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO product_lots
>     (`ProductLotID`, `ProductID`, `ExpirationDate`, `LotNumber`)
> VALUES
>     (20, 1, '2022-01-01', 'Chikita22'),
>     (21, 3, '2023-12-01', 'Florida-9'),
>     (22, 4, NULL, 'HANES-001'),
>     (23, 1, '2024-01-01', 'Chikita24')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE product_locations
>     (`ProductLocationID` int, `ProductLotID` int, `LocationCode` varchar(11), `LocationType` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO product_locations
>     (`ProductLocationID`, `ProductLotID`, `LocationCode`, `LocationType`)
> VALUES
>     (30, 20, 'A-01-01-01', 1),
>     (31, 21, 'A-02-01-01', 1),
>     (32, 22, '12-03-01-01', 2),
>     (33, 23, 'A-01-01-01', 1)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE location_inventory_adjustment_items
>     (`LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID` int, `LocationInventoryAdjustmentID` int, `ProductLocationID` int, `Count` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO location_inventory_adjustment_items
>     (`LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID`, `LocationInventoryAdjustmentID`, `ProductLocationID`, `Count`)
> VALUES
>     (40, 50, 30, 100),
>     (41, 51, 31, 200),
>     (42, 52, 32, 300),
>     (43, 53, 33, 150)
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE location_inventory_adjustments
>     (`LocationInventoryAdjustmentID` int, `LocationTypeID` int, `ReasonID` int, `Created` date)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO location_inventory_adjustments
>     (`LocationInventoryAdjustmentID`, `LocationTypeID`, `ReasonID`, `Created`)
> VALUES
>     (50, 1, 4, '2020-01-01'),
>     (51, 1, 4, '2020-05-01'),
>     (52, 2, 4, '2020-06-01'),
>     (53, 1, 4, '2020-07-07')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE location_inventory_adjustment_reasons
>     (`ReasonID` int, `Name` varchar(27), `Description` varchar(65))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO location_inventory_adjustment_reasons
>     (`ReasonID`, `Name`, `Description`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Discarded Product', 'Trash'),
>     (2, 'In-Bound Shipment', 'Delivery'),
>     (3, 'Out-Bound Shipment', 'Product was shipped out'),
>     (4, 'Out-Bound Shipment - FBA US', 'Product was shipped out to an Amazon fulfillment center in the US'),
>     (5, 'Out-Bound Shipment - FBA UK', 'Product was shipped out to an Amazon fulfillment center in the U')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     p.`ProductID`,
>     p.`ProductName`,
>     lot.`ProductLotID`,
>     lot.`ExpirationDate`,
>     lot.`LotNumber`,
>     lia.`LocationInventoryAdjustmentID`,
>     lia.`Created`,
>     liai.`count`
> FROM products AS p
> INNER JOIN product_lots AS lot ON lot.ProductID = p.ProductID
>     AND NOT EXISTS (
>         SELECT 1
>         FROM product_lots AS lot0
>         WHERE lot0.ProductID = lot.ProductID
>             AND lot0.ProductLotID > lot.ProductLotID
>     )
> INNER JOIN product_locations AS pl ON pl.ProductLotID = lot.ProductLotID
>     AND NOT EXISTS (
>         SELECT 1
>         FROM product_locations AS pl0
>         WHERE pl0.`ProductLotID` = pl.`ProductLotID`
>             AND pl0.ProductLocationID > pl.ProductLocationID
>     )
> INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustment_items AS liai ON liai.ProductLocationID = pl.ProductLocationID
>     AND NOT EXISTS (
>         SELECT 1
>         FROM location_inventory_adjustment_items AS liai0
>         WHERE liai0.ProductLocationID = liai.ProductLocationID
>             AND liai0.`LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID` > liai.`LocationInventoryAdjustmentItemID`
>     )
> INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustments AS lia ON lia.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID = liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID
> INNER JOIN location_inventory_adjustment_reasons AS liar ON liar.ReasonID = lia.ReasonID
> WHERE liar.`Name` LIKE '%Out-Bound%'
> ORDER BY p.ProductID ASC, liai.LocationInventoryAdjustmentID
> ```
>
> ```
> ProductID | ProductName | ProductLotID | ExpirationDate | LotNumber | LocationInventoryAdjustmentID | Created    | count
> --------: | :---------- | -----------: | :------------- | :-------- | ----------------------------: | :--------- | ----:
>         1 | Banana      |           23 | 2024-01-01     | Chikita24 |                            53 | 2020-07-07 |   150
>         3 | Orange      |           21 | 2023-12-01     | Florida-9 |                            51 | 2020-05-01 |   200
>         4 | Shirt       |           22 | null           | HANES-001 |                            52 | 2020-06-01 |   300
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=389a5dd959978f254de9163a9846e3a1)*

Comment: No change in the results unfortunately.

Comment: it runs on mysql 5.6 as you can see in my changed answer, maybe it is time to upgrade and next time make directly a dbfiddle example of your data

Comment: interesting. I will change a few things in the dbfiddle like multiple product locations vs a single product location. Yeah, it is time to upgrade.